# Powershell : I am trying to run a script on a remote server. The script is for gathering info of that remote and other servers in the same domain

Tags: powershell

**Editing to be clear with the issue**

****I am running the below code from a local computer which should run the script Test.ps1 placed on $server at C:\Temp to collect data from $server and other servers.****

**When i perform this, the script runs but i only get data for the $server and not the others. While if i run the C:\Temp\Test.ps1 script sitting on the $server, i get the desired output for all servers.**

I am using this code

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $credential
Invoke-Command -Session $s -Command {C:\Temp\Test.ps1}
```

I am getting the output for the remote server on which the code is placed (localhost for the script), buti am not getting any output for the other servers.

While if I run the script locally on the remote server i get output from all the servers

Comment: You may provide a local script file with the parameter `-FilePath` instead of `-Command`

Comment: This is a very common/daily practice. ['PowerShell run a command on a remote computer remoting capture in a csv'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+run+a+command+on+a+remote+computer+remoting+capture+in+a+csv%27&t=h_&ia=web). ['PowerShell run a script on a remote computer remoting capture in a csv'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+run+a+script+on+a+remote+computer+remoting+capture+in+a+csv%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: Add a `Start-Process` in front of it.

Comment: It depends on how your remote script uses credentials to access other servers. This should be a double hop issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ashleymcglone/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely

Comment: We don't know what your Test.ps1 script is doing so hard to tell you why it is doing what it is doing.  While running the script locally are you using the same credentials as when you are running it on the server?

Comment: @MikeL'Angelo Yes exactly, a case of double hop. i need to figure out the possibilities from the blog you provided. i cant use CredSSP so need to look for other options.

Comment: @Daniel the script is just querying a service for my test scenario. yes using same credentials in both the cases.

Comment: You are using WMI/CIM to query the service?  Can you query the service on the remote servers from the server itself, say if you connect to a PSSession on the server and query the services? (Enter-PSSession and run the command interactively)

Comment: just a get-service cmdlet.
When i run on the remote i am not doing a PS session, just the query script

Comment: @darc Easy to implement: Pass fresh credentials inside the Invoke-Command scriptblock ($using:cred).

Answer (score 1):

The script does not have to be on the remote host. PowerShell allows you to run local PS1 scripts on remote computers.

> Running Remote Commands
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.1
>
> Run a Script
>
> To run a script on one or many remote computers, use the FilePath
> parameter of the Invoke-Command cmdlet. The script must be on or
> accessible to your local computer. The results are returned to your
> local computer.
>
> For example, the following command runs the DiskCollect.ps1 script on
> the remote computers, Server01 and Server02.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01, Server02 -FilePath 'c:\Scripts\DiskCollect.ps1'
```

As for this...

> 'My requirement is to run that script from the remote host per
> security protocols'

... just use a script block as shown via the same MS Docs link

> Run a Remote Command
>
> To run a command on one or more computers, use the Invoke-Command
> cmdlet. For example, to run a Get-UICulture command on the Server01
> and Server02 remote computers, type:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01, Server02 -ScriptBlock {& .c:\Scripts\DiskCollect.ps1}
```

Of course, I just removed Get-UICulture cmdlet in the docs command, with a script to use.

Comment: My requirement is to run that script from the remote host per security protocols

Comment: Hummm; an odd requirement. If the script is all the same on each target server, this makes little sense from a risk management perspective. This is now multiple source hosts, running the same script which needs to be monitored/audited, vs a single source. A malicious type can literally change the script content on each server, and then the next time it runs, all these scripts are doing something different, vs running from a central controlled/monitored source. If the scripts are all doing the same thing, there is little need for the script at all. Just pass the commands in the block.

Comment: Ok let me re phrase my req
The script Test.ps1 placed and running from $server is for managing the services on $server and a few others.
i need to initiate the script on $server from a local one

Comment: OK, so, each script is doing different things for each server. So, then, the guidance previously provide are options for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your remote script uses credentials to access other servers. This should classify as a [double hop issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ashleymcglone/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely).

If you cannot use CredSPP, you can use [Resource-Based Kerberos Constrained Delegation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ashleymcglone/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely#resource-based-kerberos-constrained-delegation-links)
or use credentials inside the Invoke-Command scriptblock i.e. you can define a credential object on the local computer to be used in the -credentials parameter, and refer to it  with $using:cred in your scriptblock.
The article does a good job of summarizing all your options.